# Hide rows missing a certain class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a series of dynamic divs like these

```
<div id="my_unique_div">
    <div>
      <input type='checkbox'></input><label>Label 1</label><label><span class="unique">Text 1</span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type='checkbox'></input><label>Label 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type='checkbox'></input><label>Label 3</label><label><span class="unique">Text 3</span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type='checkbox'></input><label>Label 4</label><label><span class="unique">Text 4</span></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to set the display of all the divs that do not contain a span with `class="unique"` to "none" with jQuery but not sure what selector to use to grab them.

That would leave only the 2nd div above visible and hide the 1st, 3rd and 4th.

Comment: `div:not(.unique)`?

Comment: @mykaf that doesn't solve OPs problem. The div cannot have a span with the unique class. Your selector looks for divs without the unique selector.

Comment: Eek, good call, @imvain2. I missed that. Probably requires grabbing those divs, then getting the closest div.

Answer (score 1):

My answer loops all of the divs under **#my_unique_div** and looks for .unique objects and if none, add a class that sets the display to none.

```js
$("#my_unique_div div").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find(".unique").length === 0) {
    $(this).addClass("hide");
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_unique_div">
  <div>
    <input type='checkbox'></input><label>Label 1</label><label><span class="unique">Text 1</span></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type='checkbox'></input><label>Label 2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type='checkbox'></input><label>Label 3</label><label><span class="unique">Text 3</span></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type='checkbox'></input><label>Label 4</label><label><span class="unique">Text 4</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```